# Are apc_store and apc_fetch functions suitable for intensive use? (scenario described)

Tags: php, apc

In ASP.NET I use a static object persistent across sessions (object in server scope) to manage global website information.

I use it mainly to load-manage big lists and avoid slow database queries when sorting and modifying information.

How can this be done with PHP?

Are apc_store and apc_fetch suitable for intensive use in this scenario?

Comment: Do you have any specific reasons to think that they might not be suitable?

Comment: You need to configure your APC cache size, so it needs to be large enough to hold the volumes of data you need

Comment: APC as an bytecode cache is superseded by OpCache, so as you upgrade to PHP 5.5. you'd need to switch to using APCu

Comment: Objects don't store directly in APC, they're serialized; so any properties (such as database connections) that can't be serialized are lost, and need to be restored in an objects __wakeup method

Comment: Hi Mark. I've never used APC so i don't know how it works. Are those methods exactly like accessing to the pointer of a static object or the object (with its data) is reloaded each time it is used?

Comment: It's all pretty well documented: fetch() retrieves data from APC and you save the result of that fetch to a variable, then you access that variable.... if you change that variable, you'd need to save again because the variable has no link to APC

Comment: If the variable has no link to APC then i can't reproduce the .NET behaviour. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: No there isn't..... PHP !== .NET - but then, PHP is a language, .NET is a framework. PHP has resources, but resources cannot be maintained between requests, they're established within the execution of a script, can be used during the execution of that script, and are disconnected when the script terminates, so a resource is not persistent.

Comment: I understand. So... how could i work around that? Run a java program in the server and call it from php code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61997/discussion-between-saintjob2-0-and-mark-baker).